# is it possible to access apple external accessories framework and use with any device that is "Made For Apple"? without API?

Tags: ios, external-accessory

I am wondering if i can develop an iOS application with any device that is made for apple even thought i do not have an API nor the protocol used? I mean is there a way that I can use the devices.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by 'use'. Please elaborate.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't seem to be programmatic related.

Comment: in developing an iOS application that measures the blood pressure.. @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to detect whenever an external accessory is plugged into an iPhone/iPad and communicate with that device?

Without using the official API from the developer of that accessory, you'd have to reverse-engineer its protocol, and that might get you into trouble for copyright reasons.

You can get started with using external accessories on iDevices [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html), though it won't help you much without knowing how to communicate with a specific device.